# Python function returns empty list

Tags: python

I've been working on this task for a while, the task is to write a function that translated a text in english to swedish. I've created a dicitonary with key & value, where key is the english word and value is the swedish word.

**HOW I'VE BEEN THINKING:**
I was thinking of that there should be 2 for loops. First one should iterate thru keys and values in the dictionary, and the second one should iterate thru the string, after that there should be a condition where it checks if key in the dictionary is equals to the word in the string.
if so, append the value of the key to the list.

**THE PROBLEM**:
The function returns an empty list.

**HERE'S MY CODE**:

```
def translate(a):
    trs = {"merry":"god", "christmas":"jul", "and":"och", "happy":"gott", "new":"nytt", "year":"år"}
    translated = []
    for k, v in trs.iteritems():
        for i in a.split(" "): 
            if trs[k] == i:
                translated.append(trs[v])
    return translated

print translate("merry christmas and happy new year")
```

Comment: In your loop, you already have `k` as a key from `trs` and `v` as its value. Why are you putting them back into `trs` as keys, like `trs[k]` and `trs[v]`?

Comment: "if key in the dictionary is equals to the word in the string" well no you are checking it against `trs[k]` which is the **value**, you would need to check `if i == k` to check it against the key.

Comment: what do u mean by putting them back into trs? I want it to append the value into the list 'translated' if key in trs dictionary is equals to word in string ( i )

Comment: @tadhg-mcdonald-jensen `if k == i:` after doing this, i got the error msg: KeyError: 'och'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

The first one is that you iterate over the key-value pairs in the dictionary, and later try to use the values as keys here: `if trs[k] == i:` and here `translated.append(trs[v])` These should be just `k` and `v` instead of `trs[k]` and `trs[v]`.

The second problem is a bigger one: after fixing the previous, the code still gives wrong answer. The words are in random order. This is because you iterate over the dictionary items in the outer loop instead of the words themselves. This can easily be fixed by changing the order of the loops.

The third is that I think the function should return a string. Just return `" ".join(translated)` at the end.

And the fourth is that you actually don't use the dictionary as a dictionary. You use it as a list, but it's not how they are meant to be used. `dict`s are direct mappings of values, you don't need to iterate over all the entries all the time. Use the `in` and `[]` operators.

So here is how this code should look like:

```
def translate(a):
    trs = {"merry":"god", "christmas":"jul", "and":"och", "happy":"gott", "new":"nytt", "year":"ar"}
    translated = []
    for i in a.split(" "): 
      if i in trs:
        translated.append(trs[i])
    return " ".join(translated)

print translate("merry christmas and happy new year")
# prints "god jul och gott nytt ar"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it and letting me know what i've done wrong :D I've learned something new.

Thank you again

Answer (score 3):

```
def translate(a):
    trs = {"merry":"god", "christmas":"jul", "and":"och", "happy":"gott", "new":"nytt", "year":"ar"}
    translated = []
    for i in a.split(" "):
        for k, v in trs.iteritems():
            if i == k:
                translated.append(trs[i])
    return translated

print translate("merry christmas and happy new year")

# output:
# ['god', 'jul', 'och', 'gott', 'nytt', 'ar']
```

Answer (score 3):

- You want to preserve word order in the translation, which means that iteration over the original words should drive the algorithm (not iteration over your translation dictionary).
- There is no need to iterate over the dictionary: the purpose of a key-value data structure is to allow you to retrieve individual items quickly, by key.
- Dictionaries have a `get()` method that is handy in cases when a key might or might not exist.
- Just guessing, but it seems like the method should return text rather than a list of translated words (adjust accordingly).
- So it all boils down to this:

  ```
  return ' '.join(trs.get(w, w) for w in orig_text.split())
  ```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you were looking for:

```
trs = {"merry":"god", "christmas":"jul", "and":"och", "happy":"gott", "new":"nytt", "year":"år"}
translated = []
for i in a.split(" "):  # loop over sentence and try to translate every word
    if i in trs:  # the word to be translated is a key in your dict
        translated.append(trs[i])  # add the translation if present
    # else
    #   translated.append(i)
return ' '.join(translated)  # makes more sense than returning a list
```

Comment: Hmm? Why exactly would you ask that?

Comment: actually it wasn't wrong :D I think i might have cause a syntax error, but whatever this seems faster.

Comment: @IdontReallywolf Cheers, never mind! About performance: If you include the `else` block, you have FMc's one-liner in a more verbose version, main thing though: no more nested loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
def translate(a):
    trs = {"merry":"god", "christmas":"jul", "and":"och", "happy":"gott", "new":"nytt", "year":"år"}
    translated = []
    for i in a.split(" "):
        for k, v in trs.iteritems():
            if k == i:
                translated.append(trs[k])
return translated
```

`print translate("merry christmas and happy new year)`

In Line 6, You are doing trs[k] which wwill return value at trs[k] which is not equal to any of the substring. That's why you are getting an empty list.